# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" ?

Tags: запятая

Хорошо бы подсказать, что не так (,) и как будет лучше.

Comment: @Веста, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Хорошо бы подсказать, что не так  и как будет лучше.-однородные придаточные предложения, союз не повторяется - запятой нет.

Comment: Благодарю, Людмила!)))

Answer (score 2):

*Хорошо бы подсказать, что не так и как будет лучше.*
СПП, с однородными придаточными предложениями (союзные слова *что* и *как*) и соединительным союзом *и* между ними, запятая не ставится.

Comment: Спасибо, Дерзкий!)))

Answer (score 1):

Ответ Людмилы и Дерзкого правильный.